# Must declare table variable error with c# paramaterized query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting an error with an SQL statement:

> must declare the table variable @table

I don't know how I should fix it. Here is the code for the part that makes the query (for example 3 is Communications, 4 is Radio:basic, 5 is 45, 6 is 5, and 7 is 0).

```
string table = "Skills" + info[3];
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("use palladium; insert into @category(skill, basepercent, lvlpercent, special) values ( @skillname , @base , @lvl , @special);");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", table);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillname", info[4]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@base", info[5]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lvl", info[6]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", info[7]);
general.dbsend(cmd, connection);
```

Comment: Table name in the insert query can not be passed as parameter in SQL query. You need to have table query generated as `var query = string.Format("use palladium; insert into {0}(....", table);` and use it as `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);`

Comment: You can not pass the table name as the parameter.

Comment: This is usually an indication that your data model is broken. Data that *should* be modelled in a single table has instead been modelled as multiple tables. And worse, one or more additional columns of *data* has instead been modelled as *metadata* - to wit, it's currently embedded in your table names. I'd strongly suggest you fix the data model - every query you write that tries to query based on the mismodelled data will be a painful experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a table name as a variable in a static query. You can in a dynamic query, by formatting the table name in the query rather than supplying it as a parameter.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("use palladium; insert into ["+table.Replace("]","]]")+"](skill, basepercent, lvlpercent, special) values ( @skillname , @base , @lvl , @special);");
```

The replace bit guards against SQL Injection.